# Is it possible to add add links to Admin.aspx PWA layout page?

Tags: project-server, pwa

I need to add a new group of links to "PWA Settings" layout page (/_layouts/15/pwa/Admin/Admin.aspx).

[image]

Anyone knows is it possible and how to do it?

Comment: i think you can do it using the SharePoint deisgner or Script if you want only couple of links

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this following way:
Through SharePoint Designer you can add javascript code to master page that check page url and add your links if it is your page. But be careful with master page, add try catch blocks and etc.

Or try another way: =) 
Because you have on-premises edition you can create HttpModule, add it to GAC and include in SharePoint app web config. This HttpModule will intercept requests, check that page url is yours and add some javascript to page that render your links.